# Alternative builds using different set of dependencies on related projects

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have several projects with dependencies between them and in the production build all the projects are packaged into jars, published and the main project simply adds dependency on these jar files.

During development and CI however I would like the main project to have dependencies on the related projects and build them too as part of the process (not compile, deploy and then build next, but rather compile all together).

This mans that in production I would have:

```
compile  group:'com.me.aaa', name:'myCommonProj', version: '1.0.0'
```

while for the development builds I would like to have:

```
compile project(':myCommonProj')
```

Option #2 however requires the `settings.gradle` file.

How can I accomplish this setup?

Answer (score 0):

I'd apply [gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) to the project and work in the following way:

- in dev branch I'd keep `compile(':myProject')` dependency along with appropriate `setting.gradle` file.
- in master branch I'd keep only fixed dependencies.

This scenario isn't very comfortable however because dev branch would be merged partially (fixed vs local dependencies), but it can be quite easily done. On the other side, working this way will prevent you from keeping strange logic in build script.

Second option is *if* it all un `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`. CI server should expose build numbers and other environment variables. They can be used to include appropriate dependencies depending on environment.

Comment: I find maintaining files in separate branches error prone... In the end I added a sub folder in the build directory with an alternative `build.gradle` and an accompanying `settings.gradle` file. This means that to compile using jars I do a regular build, to build using sources I go to the subfolder.

Comment: That's why I wrote it's not very useful. Good to know which option you finally picked.